# How to upgrade the Hive version in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, azure-databricks

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Parquet does not support timestamp. See HIVE-6384;

Getting above error while executing following code in Azure Databricks.

```
spark_session.sql("""
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dev_db.processing_table
    (
      campaign STRING,
      status STRING,
      file_name STRING,
      arrival_time TIMESTAMP
    )
    PARTITIONED BY ( 
      Date DATE)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
    LOCATION "/mnt/data_analysis/pre-processed/"
""")
```

I am using hive in Azure Data bricks, and when I run a command `spark_session.conf.get("spark.sql.hive.metastore.version")` it is showing as **Hive 0.13** version.

Hive 0.13 won't have a support for **Timestamp** datatype for parquet file.

In my current dataset I have multiple columns with Timestamp datatype.
As per Hive-6384 Jira, Starting from Hive-1.2 you can use Timestamp,date types in parquet tables.

How can I upgrade the Hive/Hive metastore version?

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a related question that may answer yours:

[Databricks CREATE TABLE USING PARQUET vs. STORED AS PARQUET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72368731/databricks-create-table-using-parquet-vs-stored-as-parquet)

It looks like if you can change to `CREATE TABLE ... USING PARQUET LOCATION '...'` then it will just work without Hive JAR issues.

I don't know why though. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the version of your Databricks Runtime in Databricks cluster.
I currently use version 6.5 and able to create Hive parquet tables with Timestamp column.

Comment: I am also using databricks version 6.5, but with that I am getting hive 0.13 and with that we cant use timestamp with parquet. May I know how you are using timestamp column with parquet and what is the version of hive in your cluster ?

Comment: spark.conf.get("spark.sql.hive.metastore.version") returns me 1.2.1. Sample DDL that I have used below: create external table test.balance ( ProductCode string, Balance double) 
PARTITIONED BY (`processing_date` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
)
LOCATION 'dbfs:/mnt/<location>';