# Databricks CREATE TABLE USING PARQUET vs. STORED AS PARQUET

Tags: hive, databricks, parquet, azure-databricks

I'm creating a Databricks table in Azure backed by Parquet files in ADLS2.

I don't understand the difference between `USING PARQUET` and `STORED AS PARQUET` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

In particular, if my table has a `decimal` column the `CREATE TABLE STORED AS PARQUET location 'abfss://...'` will fail with error:

`Parquet does not support decimal. See HIVE-6384`

... unless I set properties to use a particular non-default version of Hive JARs.

On the other hand, `CREATE TABLE USING PARQUET` just works.

What's the difference?

Comment: you can check this - if you upgrade your metastore version, this should work https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2020/08/05/spark-error-parquet-does-not-support-decimal-see-hive-6384/